# How do I export a list of users into an excel spreadsheet in Drupal 9

Tags: importing-exporting, 9

I'm using a Drupal 9 website and would like to export a list of the users into an excel spreadsheet. Would using the [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: if your requirement is to only export users to excel, but not to import - Yes views data export is one of the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are willing to use drush:
Create a PHP script, named something like users_to_csv.php

```
<?php

$fields = [
            'name',
            'mail',
            'langcode',
            'preferred_langcode',
            'timezone',
            'created',
            'changed',
          ];

$users = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
            ->getStorage('user')
            ->loadByProperties([
              // some properties here if you care to restrict the users list
            ]);

foreach ($users as $user ) {

  foreach ($fields as $field) {

    echo $user->get($field)->getValue()[0]['value'] . ', ';

  }

  echo PHP_EOL;

}
```

Then run it with

```
drush php:script users_to_csv.php > users.csv
```

The fields list is up to You.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a quick on-off, you could write a simple View and highlight and copy (Control C) the Users list on the page to a text file, or use Views Data Export and export as a CSV.